# Sending a PDF to iBooks (iPad)

Tags: ipad, macbook-pro, books

How can I send a PDF to my iBooks in iPad without having to connect the iPad to my laptop using a cable?

Is this possible at all? Or do I necessarily have to use iTunes and a cable?

Comment: Is using iTunes the issue or the cable? Remember you can do WiFi sync, no cable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

- Mail
- Dropbox
- Google Drive
- And many more

Basically you just need to be able to watch the pdf on your iPad in order to save and open it with iBooks also, you can still sync with iTunes

Comment: if you use icloud and have a mac and a ipad you can also simply import the pdf to ibooks on mac and icloud will do it for you